# Date is taking MM/dd/yyyy format which is wrong on server

Tags: c#, asp.net, date, datetime

I have a textbox and calendar control in my aspx page which is working fine on local machine with `dd-mm-yyyy` format.

But when I use the same code on my server it automatically takes `mm-dd-yyyy` format. I don't know why this is happening

Below is my code:-

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtdatefilter" runat="server" Width="70" OnTextChanged="txtdatefilter_TextChanged" ></asp:TextBox>
            <cc3:Calendar ID="CaldatefilterDt" runat="server" CultureName="en-GB" DatePickerImagePath="../Images/icon2.gif"
                DatePickerMode="true" TextBoxId="txtdatefilter" Align="Left" OnDateChanged="CaldatefilterDt_DateChanged">
            </cc3:Calendar>
```

**CS code**

```
protected void txtdatefilter_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    CaldatefilterDt.SelectedDate = Convert.ToDateTime(txtdatefilter.Text);
}

protected void CaldatefilterDt_DateChanged(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    txtdatefilter.Text = Convert.ToDateTime(CaldatefilterDt.SelectedDate, CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-GB")).ToString("dd-MM-yyyy");
}
```

Comment: What is the culture on the server ?

Comment: @BoasEnkler: `CultureName="en-GB"`

Comment: what is the culture on the browser you are using to view the page?

Comment: It is not clear what do you mean by _local machine with dd-mm-yyyy format_ and _my server it automatically takes mm-dd-yyyy format_ sentences. Final formatting is shouldn't be a problem because you _always_ format your `Datetime` with `ToString("dd-MM-yyyy")`, so I don't think this is a parsing issue or something. It would be better to clarify your question better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `DateTime.TryParseExact`:

```
protected void txtdatefilter_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DateTime dateFilter;
    if(DateTime.TryParseExact(txtdatefilter.Text, "dd-MM-yyyy", DateTimeFormatInfo.InvariantInfo, DateTimeStyles.None, out dateFilter))
        CaldatefilterDt.SelectedDate = dateFilter;
}
```

another option is to use `DateTime.Parse`(better `TryParse` with user input) and  to provide your `DateTimeFormatInfo`/ `CultureInfo`, for example `"en-GB"`(UK) or `"de-DE"`(germany):

```
bool valid = DateTime.TryParse("26-01-2016", new CultureInfo("en-GB"), DateTimeStyles.None, out dateFilter);
```

The first option works always because it circumvents localization issues by using `DateTimeFormatInfo.InvariantInfo` or `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture`. The second option ensures that it works with the provided formatinfo/culture.

Comment: let me try and check

Comment: @coder:  i think so, don't know the calendar control you're using. But youz've already provided `CultureName="en-GB"`, so is it necessary?

Comment: Tim: I don't think so. Also ur code, is working fine on server. But I still didn't got the reason why it was taking the other format by default. Any special **reason**

Comment: @coder: maybe because your webserver uses a different culture like `en-US`. You can look at the control-panel/region and language which format he uses for dates.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code:

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact(txtdatefilter.Text.ToString(), "MM/dd/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

string s = dt.ToString("dd/M/yyyy");
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture`:

```
Convert.ToDateTime(txtdatefilter.Text.ToString(), CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```